# How to restrict WPF WindowsFormHost height according to Window size/resolutions

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using third party tool **(AxInterop.EDOfficeLib dll)** to show excel sheet in WPF user control. By using this sheet user can create custom report.

**Following is my XAML :**

```
 <DockPanel  Margin="0,0,0,0" LastChildFill="False" Name="PanelCustomeReport">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid Background="{DynamicResource OMSToolBarBlueGradientBrush}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                        <WindowsFormsHost>
                                            <edrawOffViewer:AxEDOffice x:Name="framer" NotifyCtrlReady="framer_NotifyCtrlReady"/>
                                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
```

**Problem :**

When i resize the form in running mode `WindowsFormHost` control not set its height and width accordingly.

For more clear view please refer snapshot :

[image]

As you can see in the snapshot green line is the end of the grid but `windowformhost` exceed as red line. How i can restrict it with in the Grid only.

If more information need please let me know. I will try to provide it.

Comment: have yout tried ViewBox?

Comment: please let me know how i can use ViewBox here ?

Comment: Not working still having same issue :-(

Comment: try  <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">

Comment: It still comes outside from bottom ....

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ViewBox here it may help you.

```
<Viewbox>
    <DockPanel  Margin="0,0,0,0" LastChildFill="False" Name="PanelCustomeReport">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid Background="{DynamicResource OMSToolBarBlueGradientBrush}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                        <WindowsFormsHost>
                                            <edrawOffViewer:AxEDOffice x:Name="framer" NotifyCtrlReady="framer_NotifyCtrlReady"/>
                                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
</Viewbox>
```